# How to set default filter in datatable while server side processing?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables server side processing to get data. Right now its a simple implmentation of the server side processing and working fine.

My database table has status col. which has status of Active or Inactive. I just want datatables to get Active records only, right now its getting everything.

How do I apply so whether the user is sorting, searching etc. but datatables is doing only for records that have the status of Active only ?

My code is following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#tblProducts').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 50,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [ 8,9,10 ]
            }
        ],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            url :"ssp-products.php", // json datasource
            type: "get"  // type of method  , by default would be get
        }
    }); 

    table.on ('draw', function () {
        $(".thickbox").colorbox({ inline:true, width:"75%", height:"75%" });
        $(".ajax").colorbox({ width:"75%", height:"75%" });
    });
     
});       
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to retrieve inactive records optionally, or do you want to only ever retrieve active records? If it's the latter, are you able to modify your database query to take this into account?